# Appending values from range to list in Appscripts (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

What am I doing wrong? I am just trying to append a value after iterating over some cells.
however, what I am appending is something like this: `[Ljava.lang.Object;@780acde2`

```
function record_ticker(){

  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PORTFOLIO');
  var date= new Date();
  tickerprice=[];
  var tickervalue=sheet.getRange(3,1).getValues();
  for (cell =0; cell<tickervalue.length; cell++){
    console.log(cell);
    tickerprice.push(cell);
  }

  var dest=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('HISTORIC_TICKER');
  dest.appendRow([date,tickerprice]);
}
```

Comment: Just means that the value you're setting is not a primitive value type like string, but a object. Note here that `typeof tickerprice !== "string"`

Comment: `function record_ticker(){
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet0'); 
  var dest=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  dest.appendRow([new Date(),sheet.getRange(3,1).getValue()]);
}`